# Find Total Page count in Wowbook jQuery flipbook plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate the jquery flipbook in my page (built with asp.net mvc). I have selected [jQuery WowBook plugin](https://github.com/yapro/wowbook) for the same. ([here is the documentation](http://www.neuearbeit.de/wow_book_plugin/documentation/)) Now I have integrated major all but one thing I am trying to find but I can't. I have one textbox in which user can enter page number and that page will be opened. I know that we can go to any page by

I want to find **Total Page Number** or **Last Page number** so that I can validate entering maximum page number.

Does any one can help me? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says:

```
var book = $.wowBook("#some_element");

alert("This book has "+book.pages.length+" pages.");
```